# Does vite not resolve alias in css/scss section of a vue file?

Tags: vite, quasar-framework

Does vite not resolve aliases like `~assets` in css/scss section of vue files?

I'm currently in the process of switching form old quasar-cli with webpack to quasar-cli-vite and stumbled - among other - over this issue. But I'm not sure if I missed something, especially because I couldn't find anything online describing the same issue.

Reproduction is easy by setting up a default Quasar App with `npm init quasar`, choosing

- Quasar 2
- quasar-cli-vite
- ESLint with standard profile
  and modifying the `src/pages/indexPage.vue` to add a div block with a background image set via css:

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <img
      alt="Quasar logo"
      src="~assets/quasar-logo-vertical.svg"
      style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
    >
    <div class="bg-quasar-logo"></div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.bg-quasar-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: center / contain no-repeat #f345aa url("~assets/quasar-logo-vertical.svg");
}
</style>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'IndexPage'
})
</script>
```

If I use `assets`, i.e. without `~` in the css background-url it works, but not with `~`. Why isn't it the same as in html templates or js imports? Does vite even use the `~assets` alias to resolve the url in the css section, or does it just work by chance?

Comment: Just a little more testing shows, it actually does resolve the aliases without `~`.

Comment: In your code you're using the asset within you template AND within your style. I'm using it only within my style. And for me it seems that ~assets won't get resolved with Qusar 2/Vite. Any ideas?